# python3: command not found

Tags: python-3.x, docker, shell

I have a dockerfile in which I have specified the entrypint as shell script named `run-services.sh`
Contents of the shell script are as follows:

```
apache2ctl start

echo "Started apache2ctl..."

python3 mock_ta.py
```

Now when I deploy this service at my local machine I get an error saying
`python3: command not found`

I removed entrypoint and went inside the container and executed the `which python3` command and I can see that python3 is installed at `/usr/bin/python3`.
Ideally it should run the python script if python is installed, right? Any idea why this happens?

============================================================

**Edit:**Added Dockerfile****

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

# Utilities
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https git curl vim --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# SimpleSAMLphp
ARG SIMPLESAMLPHP_VERSION=1.15.2
RUN curl -s -L -o /tmp/simplesamlphp.tar.gz https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/releases/download/v$SIMPLESAMLPHP_VERSION/simplesamlphp-$SIMPLESAMLPHP_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf /tmp/simplesamlphp.tar.gz -C /tmp && \
    rm -f /tmp/simplesamlphp.tar.gz  && \
    mv /tmp/simplesamlphp-* /var/www/simplesamlphp && \
    touch /var/www/simplesamlphp/modules/exampleauth/enable
COPY config/simplesamlphp/config.php /var/www/simplesamlphp/config
COPY config/simplesamlphp/authsources.php /var/www/simplesamlphp/config
COPY config/simplesamlphp/saml20-sp-remote.php /var/www/simplesamlphp/metadata
COPY config/simplesamlphp/server.crt /var/www/simplesamlphp/cert/
COPY config/simplesamlphp/server.pem /var/www/simplesamlphp/cert/

# Apache
COPY config/apache/ports.conf /etc/apache2
COPY config/apache/simplesamlphp.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
COPY config/apache/cert.crt /etc/ssl/cert/cert.crt
COPY config/apache/private.key /etc/ssl/private/private.key
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf && \
    a2enmod ssl && \
    a2dissite 000-default.conf default-ssl.conf && \
    a2ensite simplesamlphp.conf

COPY config/run-services.sh /var/www/simplesamlphp/config/run-services.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/simplesamlphp/config/run-services.sh"]

# Set work dir
WORKDIR /var/www/simplesamlphp

# General setup
EXPOSE 8080 8443
```

Comment: Typical best practice is to run only one program in a container; so run the reverse proxy in one container, and run a custom image `FROM python` with your application in a second container.  In this setup, if Apache were to fail, you wouldn't notice.  Otherwise, can you edit the question to include a [mcve], including your Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have added the dockerfile

Comment: That's a PHP image and I wouldn't expect it to include Python unless you specifically install it.

Comment: @Jeet : How did you ensure inside `run-services.sh`  that the Python directory is in the PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @David

With your help I was able to figure out that the python3 image that was present inside container was not accessible indeed.

So I had to install python3 and pip packages with the help of following command
`RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y python3 && apt install -y python3-pip`